# Update but only what is different (what've changed)

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I've tried something like this:

```
UPDATE Person 
SET Name = @Name, Phone = @Phone, Email = @Email, Status = @Status 
WHERE Id = @Id AND Name != @Name AND Phone != @Phone AND Email != @Email AND Status != @Status;
```

But isn't working.

Comment: Try replacing AND by OR in the WHERE clause.

Comment: What's the harm if you update the columns to the same values? Do you have some sort of trigger that you don't want to run?

Comment: @McNets That will update virtually _every_ row in the table with the parameter values

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? You get an error? Unexpected results? Something else?

Comment: I suspect you meant for `Id = @Id AND` to remain the same, and then the rest of the clauses to be changed to `OR`s within a single set of parentheses, @McNets ?

Comment: Can any of your columns (or variables) have a `NULL` value?

Comment: @Larnu Nope. I'm afraid of null values, I never allow them

Comment: *"I never allow them"* That's a problem... What do you do if you don't know the value of something? What do you put in for Email is something doesn't have an email? `NULL` isn't something to be "scared" of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Id` is your primary key then you probably want:

```
UPDATE Person 
SET Name = @Name, Phone = @Phone, Email = @Email, Status = @Status 
WHERE Id = @Id AND 
   (Name != @Name OR Phone != @Phone OR Email != @Email OR Status != @Status);
```

But there generally isn't any harm in updating columns to the same value unless you have some sort of trigger that you don't want to run. Even with the code above, if only *one* of the column values changes, you're going to "update" the other three to their same value.

Comment: It worked, the thing is that cells like CreationDate I don't wanna them to be updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to prevent unnecessary updates.
It is using set based operator `INTERSECT`, and it won't trip on NULL values in comparison:

```
AND (Name != @Name OR Phone != @Phone OR Email != @Email)
```

The solution is using *UpdatedOn* *DATETIMEOFFSET(3)* column to track the updated DateTime.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @person TABLE (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    Name VARCHAR(20), 
    Phone VARCHAR(15), 
    Email VARCHAR(128), 
    UpdatedOn DATETIMEOFFSET(3)
);
INSERT @person (ID, Name, Phone, Email, UpdatedOn) VALUES
(1, 'Peter', '1-305-803-1234', 'peter@gmail.com', NULL),
(2, 'Paul', NULL, 'paul@gmail.com', NULL);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @person;

DECLARE @ID INT = 1
    , @Name VARCHAR(20) = 'Peter' -- try 'PeterZ'
    , @Phone VARCHAR(15) = '1-305-803-1234'
    , @Email VARCHAR(128) = 'peter@gmail.com';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT @ID AS ID
        , @Name AS NAme
        , @Phone AS Phone
        , @Email AS Email
)
UPDATE T 
SET Name = S.Name, Phone = S.Phone, Email = S.Email
   , T.UpdatedOn = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
FROM @person AS T       -- target
    INNER JOIN rs AS S  -- source
      ON T.ID = S.ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT S.* 
            INTERSECT SELECT T.ID, T.Name, T.Phone, T.Email);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @person;
```